# Scala Play Production start not working (assets folder not available)

Tags: scala, playframework

I am able to run play in dev mode fine by using

```
./activator run
```

However when I trying to deploy my code in prod by

```
./activator start
```

I am getting below error when trying to access home page

```
 [info] play - Application started (Prod)
 [info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
 [error] application - 

! @6pikee0l8 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[FileNotFoundException: /Users/vikashkumar/Documents/example/target/universal/stage/public/html/index.html (No such file or directory)]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:205) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$14$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:202) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.9.jar:2.3.9]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/vikashkumar/Documents/example/target/universal/stage/public/html/index.html (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:90) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:75) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.5.jar:na]
```

Details

```
   scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
```

Plugin.sbt

```
  addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.9")
```

One more point is, I am using index.html placed at public/html/index.html for as index page instead of using play template.

Looks like assets (plugin/html , css etc) folder is not exposed in production

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`sbt` should be more than able to run your code. why are you using activator?

use `sbt run` to start your application, instead of the `activator start` black box